# Display Progress of Function using Pool.map

Tags: python

I'm writing a script which parses multiple logs. Initially it did not use multiprocessing. within the a function I have it display the current progress with percent using stdout.write.

When I switched to using multiprocessing.Pool.map, the progress sits right on top of each other. The script on its own works properly it does the job, I need it to display properly to the terminal.

```
PROGRESS: 1 of 119          PERCENT: 1%          FILE: file1.txt
```

So sometimes it will display file1 sometimes file2 sometimes file3...etc.

I would like it to display

```
PROGRESS: 1 of 119          PERCENT: 1%          FILE: file1
PROGRESS: 1 of 119          PERCENT: 1%          FILE: file2
PROGRESS: 1 of 119          PERCENT: 1%          FILE: file3
```

This is my first post so forgive my lack of experience. Below is a part of the code.

```
    def parseFiles(x):
       try:
           for stuff in stuffs:
              stuff += stuff
           progress = "PROGRESS: %s of %s" %(csvlist[3], getMaxSends(x))
           percent = "PERCENT: {0:.0f}%".format(float(csvlist[3])/float(getMaxSends(x)) * 100)
           curFile = "FILE: %s" %x
           sys.stdout.write("          %s          %s          %s\r" %(progress, percent, curFile))
           sys.stdout.flush()

        except:
           pool.terminate()
    try:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        pool.map(parseFiles, sendfiles)

        pool.terminate()
        os.chdir(args.directory[0])

    except:
        pool.terminate()
        os.chdir(args.directory[0])
        subprocess.call("rm *_send *_recv", shell = True)
        subprocess.call("rm *.csv", shell = True)
        print "\n\nSTATUS: FAILED"
        print "I TOLD YOU THIS WOULD ALL END IN TEARS\n"
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong because I didn't understand your desired output format - it got mangled, but I just fixed it. I don't know how to update output on any line that's not the last without using something like [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html). You might be able to hack something similar into [`python-progressbar`](https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/), though.